# How to enable exFAT for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: external-hdd, 20.04, raspberrypi, exfat

Today I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1008-raspi aarch64) on my Raspberry PI, and I know that exFAT should be supported by the 5.4 kernel, but whenever I try to mount an external drive, I get an error

```bsh
$ sudo mount -t exfat /etc/sda1 /media/wd
mount: /media/wd: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'.
```

And here is the output of `cat /proc/filesystems`

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   cpuset
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   configfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   devpts
    ext3
    ext2
    ext4
    squashfs
    vfat
nodev   ecryptfs
    fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
nodev   mqueue
nodev   pstore
    btrfs
nodev   autofs
```

Do you need to do anything additionally to enable the support for exFAT?

Thank you

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`?

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to use FUSE and it says that Ubuntu 20.04 comes with native support for exFAT. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Linux_Kernel

Comment: This is strange behavior.  Out of curiosity I setup a clean 20.04 installation in a VM and exFAT support worked flawlessly without the need to install anything else.  Maybe since the kernel is for a Raspberry Pi and not AMD64 or i386, it might be missing the exFAT support?  Could be a bug.  I guess I will have to setup a Raspberry Pi to confirm it.

Comment: I was looking around the release notes to see if this is only for AMD64 and i386, but couldn't find any information. And since it is a fresh release, there is not much information around the net.

Comment: @MirkoAkov Can you by chance edit your question and add the output of `cat /proc/filesystems`?  On my VM install with AMD64 the exfat is right at the bottom of the list, but on my RPi4 20.04 install, it wasn't listed there.  The `/proc/filesystems` file is what shows the filesystems are supported by the kernel.  So to me it appears as they didn't add the support to the kernel for exFAT.

Comment: I added the output. I don't see exFAT in there. I wonder if it is a bug or is it something intentional. I might need to go back to exfat-nofuse

Comment: I am writing an answer up that you can use to install the `exfat` support for the kernel, but you might want to file it as a bug using `ubuntu-bug` for the kernel.  They might actually give you an answer about why it is not there.

Comment: Follow the bug report filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1880503

Comment: I think it's not only in Ubuntu-Raspi. Here in Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4.0-42 also not enable. 1. The .ko file /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/exfat - available
2. Listing in /proc/filesystems - unavailable Think miss-config the exFAT in this kernel Hope somebody will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you can try.  Since the `GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1008-raspi aarch64` kernel doesn't seem to have the support for exFAT built in, you can add it.  From https://www.techrepublic.com/article/try-out-this-new-linux-exfat-kernel-module-for-improved-performance/ you can follow the steps to download and install the exFAT support for the kernel.

Install `git` if it is not installed:

```
sudo apt install git
```

You may also want the build-essential package:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Next, download the exfat-linux:

```
git clone https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux
```

Enter the newly created folder which should be `cd exfat-linux`

Then run the following to install the kernel module and make it active:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe exfat
```

Now when you run `cat /proc/filesystems` you should see `exfat` at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much for the help @Terrance ‍♂️

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, please see this Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403901/1346853

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after having the fuse drivers installed in an earlier version then upgrading to 20.04 and removing the fuse drivers. `cat /proc/filesystems | grep fat` does not show exfat.

I re-installed the kernel module included with 20.04 using:
`sudo modprobe -v exfat`

`cat /proc/filesystems | grep fat` now shows exfat.
Then to make it survive a reboot, I added exfat to `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

Comment: This worked for me on 20.04, linux 5.4.0-144, after I removed exfat-fuse and exfat-utils.

As the drive didn't automount I created an exFAT folder in /media and mounted it from the command line:
'sudo mount -t exfat PARTUUID=5a5a18d1-01 /media/john/exFAT/'

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix I found on my amd64 Ubuntu 20.04.

The fuse support gets called first if you have exfat-fuse installed.

1. I renamed /sbin/mount.exfat.fuse to /sbin/mount.exfat.fuse-save
2. I renamed /sbin/mount.exfat-save to  /sbin/mount.exfat-save
   (so if I screw up I can revert them)
3. I checked that exfat.ko existed in /lib/modules/5.4.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/
4. I insmod-ed the exfat.ko (which I found wasn't necessary after the renaming of the mount commands above.
5. I called /bin/mount to add the external drive and it mounted.
6. I called umount to remove the mounted filesystem.
7. I rmmod'd the exfat.ko and checked it just worked without insmod being forced.
8. I apt removed exfat-fuse and removed the two saved renamed mount files above since they get called BEFORE the system mount command.

Hope that helps some folks.  I think that were all the troubleshooting steps.

Ubuntu should put this in the release notes so others don't have the old fuse-mount versions loading first.

Answer (score 1):

The new exFAT kernel driver was in Staging in 5.4 and fully released in 5.7.

See:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/linux-5-4-kernel-release-features
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/linux-5-7-kernel-features

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to run `sudo apt install exfat-utils` before it stopped being greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Distilling the above answers to their simplest form, for 20.04:

```
sudo apt install exfat-utils
sudo apt remove exfat-fuse
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sde1 /mnt/exfat
```

Of course, mounting by UUID is better than /dev/sdX1 as the names change depending on what's plugged in first.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.14 I gave up on the old gparted and just used parted;

```
B="/dev/sda"
sudo modprobe exfat
sudo parted "$B" mktable msdos
sudo parted "$B" mkpart primary 0% 100%
sudo mkfs.exfat "${B}1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo mount -t exfat /etc/sda1 /media/wd
```

`etc`... to be replace with `dev` and it will work. Even on Ubuntu Core it works out of the box.