# How do I format a partition to exFAT in GNOME Disks? "exFAT" is greyed out

Tags: 21.10, exfat, gnome-disk-utility

I'm trying to use GNOME Disks to format a USB stick to exFAT. If I create a new partition, I see this dialog:

[image: Screenshot]

If I select "Other", I am presented with these choices:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the "exFAT" radio button is greyed out and disabled. How do I enable it? How do I format a partition to exFAT using GNOME Disks on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit your question and add which version of Ubuntu, and kernel you are using. Older kernels don't have exFAT support by default. Can you read/write exFAT formatted partitions in this computer?

Comment: Also see [How to enable exFAT for Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234755/how-to-enable-exfat-for-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 but I'm also interested in knowing the answer for other versions of Ubuntu. I'm using the kernel `Linux song-ubuntu-desktop 5.13.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP` but I'm also interested in knowing the answer for other kernel versions.

Comment: I am using 20.04 and exFAT is not grayed out in my Gnome Disks. I must have installed support at some point. I have both `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed. Try installing these two (if available in the 21.10 repositories) and see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 22.04 *exfatprogs* package needs to be installed to enable this option
`apt install exfatprogs`

Comment: Perfect, that worked. I installed it and restarted the Files program and the option became available.

Answer (score 2):

The options greyed out do not have tools installed for those filesystems.   In some cases, those filesystems can be mounted in linux, but not created.

For example until very recently, NTFS and exfat could only be created in windows.  Only recently were tools for these available in linux.

Possibly the option would become available if you installed the appropriate exfat tools, assuming they are available for the version of Ubuntu you are using.  In Ubuntu 20.04, `apt install exfat-utils` will install these tools.

Comment: NTFS can be created in Linux and is listed on OP's screenshot.

Comment: What are the appropriate tools that need to be installed on Ubuntu to enable GNOME Disks to format a partition in exFAT?

Comment: Huh.  NTFS was added while I blinked.    Answer updated for both comments.

Comment: @user10489 if you search this site you will find answers to how to create NTFS partitions in Ubuntu from way back in 2012. That was 10 years ago!