# How do I change the permission for the mount folder for my drive in Ubuntu 22.04, with exfat-utils unavailable?

Tags: apt, server, 22.04, exfat

Earlier there was a package named exfat-utils which allowed dump feature. With this package installed on my machine I could change the permission of the folder in which I mounted my exfat drive but in Ubuntu 22.04 this package is removed and I can't change permission of my mounted folder. Someone please help me. Both exfat-fuse and exfatprogs are installed on system but problem still exists.

Comment: You might need both `exfat-fuse` and `exfatprogs`

Comment: exfat does not support Unix/POSIX permissions or ownership

Comment: I think [this answers your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403900/how-to-install-exfat-utils-and-hddtemp-on-ubuntu-22-04).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install exfat-utils and hddtemp on ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403900/how-to-install-exfat-utils-and-hddtemp-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 3):

exfat doesn't support POSIX permissions.

You can only change permissions with mount options when it is mounted.  The exfat utils have little to do with this, unless you are using them to mount the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 22.04 now provides exfat support directly from the kernel. `exfat-utils` has been deprecated. Install `exfatprogs` instead to have all utilities for working with the exfat file system.

Tools included are `mkfs.exfat` to create an exFAT filesystem, `fsck.exfat` to check and repair an exFAT filesystem, and `tune.exfat` to print and edit the filesystem label.

Note that you do not need these tools to change permissions on the mount point (which you referred to as the "mounted folder"). Changing ownership and permissions of the mount point can be done as usual using `chown` and `chmod`. The exfat file system does *not* support linux permissions. Files on the exfat file system will inherited the permissions of the mount point.