# No exfat support Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: partitioning, mount, exfat

I'm trying to enable support for exfat devices on my Ubuntu OS. It's running version 22.04.2 LTS with the Gnome desktop. I used the command `sudo apt install exfatprogs` but I'm still unable to format a disk as exfat. I receive this [exfat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRZVZ.png). I tried the steps on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403900/how-to-install-exfat-utils-and-hddtemp-on-ubuntu-22-04) with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a shorter volume label? it may be limited to 11 characters

Comment: I tried using a shorter volume label and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get exfat working by installing exfatprogs and reducing the characters on the volume label. I neglected to include spaces as a character. It is limited to a certain amount of characters but I'm not sure how many. I was able to use it by naming the volume with fat selected and then selecting other followed by exfat.

Answer (score 0):

Just found I have the same problem since system was updated a couple of weeks ago
Running
$ find /lib/modules/ -iname '*exfat*'

The system comes back with ..............
/lib/modules/5.19.0-43-generic/kernel/fs/exfat
/lib/modules/5.19.0-43-generic/kernel/fs/exfat/exfat.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-75-generic/kernel/fs/exfat
/lib/modules/5.15.0-75-generic/kernel/fs/exfat/exfat.ko

Running
$ uname -r

The system comes back with ..................
5.19.0-45-generic

I wonder if there is an incompatibility between the Kernel and the version of exfat modules.

I had this problem in March when I first updated to 22.04 - I changed the  Kernel to get it working.

Could the same have happened again ?