Solution for E: Package 'exfat-utils' has no installation candidate
I am failing to install this package on Ubuntu 22.04

After, checking around, I realized exfat-utils has been replaced by exfatprogs  (see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403901/1724919),
So instead use:
sudo apt install exfatprogs


$ apt search --names-only exfat
[...]
exfatprogs/jammy,now 1.1.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  tools to create, check and label exFAT filesystems
[...]

You spelled it wrong.  Try exfatprogs
